# How many ordered subsets of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations

> We have a set $A$ consisting of $n$ elements.
>
> Is there a closed form for
>   the total number of 
>   subsets when you care about the order of the elements in the subsets?

---

Lets call the number of subsets $T(n)$

$$T(n) = \binom{n}{0}0!+
\binom{n}{1}1!+
\binom{n}{2}2!+
\cdots
+\binom{n}{n}n!
$$

Which is the same as

$$P(n,0) + P(n,1) + P(n,2) + \cdots + P(n,n)$$

The "related" sum of combinations have a nice closed form.

$$C(n,0) + C(n,1) + C(n,2) + \cdots + C(n,n) = 2^n$$

---

If we factor out a $n$ we get

$$T(n) = 1 + n\left[
\binom{n-1}{0}0!+
\binom{n-1}{1}1!+
\cdots
+\binom{n-1}{n-1}(n-1)!
\right]$$

and the recurrence equation

$$T(n) = 1 +nT(n-1)$$

Is there a closed form for the solution
of this for particular n?

I know that in the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}T(n) = e \cdot n!$$

Comment: Well, the OEIS doesn't offer anything much better than what you have.  Still, it may offer you some leads:   [A002627](https://oeis.org/search?q=A002627&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: @lulu I believe that is missing a term.  The matching reference is https://oeis.org/A000522.

Comment: Thanks both, i did not know about  that site.

Comment: @ErickWong  You are absolutely right.  I started my sequence with $T(1)=1$, but it ought to have been $2$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica gives $e \times \Gamma(n+1,1)$ where $$\Gamma(a, z) = \int_z^{\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t} dt$$
is the incomplete gamma function. It's not much of a simplification, I know, but I don't think $\Gamma(a, 1)$ has a nicer closed form.

Comment: +1 But its something :)

Answer (score 3):

As the previous answer mentioned, we can write the solution as $e\Gamma(n+1,1)$, which in turn can be written as 
$$e\bigg(n!-\int_0^1t^ne^{-t}dt\bigg)$$ 
Notice that this will monotonously approach $en!$ as $n$ goes to infinity, and that it will be within $en!\pm0.5$ already at $n=2$. Since the solution must be an integer, we can simply round $en!$ off to the nearest integer, so long as $n\ge2$.
For $n$ being $0$ and $1$, then the solution is $1$ and $2$. Therefore my answer is:
$$T(n)=
    \begin{cases}
      \text{round}(en!) & ,n>1\\
      2 & ,n=1\\
      1 & ,n=0\\
      \end{cases}$$